# Is there a way to make automatic formatting based on keywords in an array in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I'm making a spreadsheet to track my macros in an attempt to eat healthier.
`="Calories: "&SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B5:L5, "([0-9]+)cal")), 0)) &char(10)& "Protein: "&SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B5:L5, "P: ([0-9]+)g")), 0))&"g"`

This looks at the information given in the cells (E.G. "Salad 320cal P:32) and parses out the data based on the prefix and suffix of the given data.

I would like to make this process even simpler, mainly by using an array of already made data, and using the title of the phrase ("Salad") to call to the data in the array just by typing in the cells.

Is there any setup or function I can use to reroute the data to an array based on a string?

Here is a link to a copy of my spreadsheet with a hopefully more clear set of instructions
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dWu4UKlZdvK_1ZjM8dNb-l87RXmhs8eB7k4B2Bk0ATs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I've updated it with the link to the spreadsheet .

Answer (score 0):

try vlookup:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B3:L3, O11:P21, 2, 0)))
```

and use it as input for your total formula

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I messed up while using VLOOKUP before. Out of curiosity, what does the IFNA function do in this function?

Comment: @vFreeze if VLOOKUP is not able to find something it will output error so IFNA is there to hide that error message

Comment: Awesome, I've been finicking with it and I think I have a better understanding of it with that description. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:1="Total",
 IF(B3:3="",, 
   "Calories: "&SUM(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(LOWER(B3:3), LOWER($O$12:$P), 2, 0), "No Description"), "([0-9]+)cal"),"")*1)& CHAR(10) &
   " Protien: "&SUM(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(LOWER(B3:3), LOWER($O$12:$P), 2, 0), "No Description"), "([0-9]+)g"  ),"")*1)& " g"),
 IF(B3:3="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(B3:3, $O$12:$P, 2, 0), "No Description"))))
```

[image]